# How to calculate interest rate in this problem?

Tags: interest-rates, inflation, annualized, present-value, annuity

**Problem:** A loan of £12,000 is issued and is repaid in instalments of £300 at the end of each month for 4
    years. Calculate the effective annual rate of interest for this loan.

What I tried-

[image]

But how to solve this equation for i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annuity expression $a_{4}^{(12)}$is written as: 
$$a_{4}^{(12)}= \frac{1-(1+i)^{-4}}{i^{(12)}} = \frac{i}{i^{(12)}} a_4$$

where, $i$ is the effective annual rate of interest and **$i^{(12)}$ is nominal rate of interest convertible monthly**, which is equal to 
$$i^{(12)}=12((1+i)^{1/12}-1)$$
There is no closed formula to get the interest rate, you have to used **hit and trial method to get the effective rate of interest.**

To get the **initial guess**, you may use your annuity table at which $\frac{12000}{3600}$ is nearer to $a_4$.

---

**Alternative method:** Assuming $i'$ as effective monthly interest rate, then solve this equation: 
$$12000 = 300 \left[ \frac{1-(1+i')^{-48}}{i'}\right]$$
After obtaining monthly rate, convert it to effective annual interest rate using: 
$$i = (1+i')^{12} - 1$$

Answer (score 2):

There are 48 monthly payments. You can use the formula for the Present Value of an annuity:

$12000 = 300 \frac{1}{i/12}[ 1-\frac{1}{(1+i/12)^{48}}]$

to find the interest rate

However there is no explicit solution for i, it is solved by trial and error. The value I get is 9.2418%

Answer (score 2):

you can also solve this by using the PMT function and goalseek in excel. The answer is as follows:

[image]

What I did is, I first set the interest rate to 0% and calculated the monthly payment using the PMT function. Then I goalseeked the monthly interest rate such that the monthly payment would be 300.

Answer (score 0):

Soultion can be found using IRR ja EFFECT excel function

[image: Soultion can be found using IRR ja EFFECT excel function]